# BodyWithBodies on Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

How to create SKPhysicsBody bodyWithBodies?
i am new and i tried but it just wouldn't appear on the simulator.
somebody can give an example of it?
here is part of my code:

```
Bike = [SKSpriteNode node];
    Bike.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithBodies:bikeArray];
    Bike.position = CGPointMake(100, 100);
    //Bike.size = CGSizeMake(40, 50);
    Bike.physicsBody.mass = 0.1;
    //Bike.physicsBody.dynamic = YES;
    Bike.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = YES;
    Bike.physicsBody.restitution = 0;
    Bike.physicsBody.friction = 0;
    Bike.physicsBody.allowsRotation = YES;
    Bike.name = @"Bike";
    [self addChild:Bike];
```

tanks,

Comment: What do you mean by "wouldn't appear"? A physics body itself doesn't look like anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
object1.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithBodies:@[object2, object3, object4]];
```

You can either list each sprite object like I did above, or stick them into an array and do it like in your code sample.

Just remember that the sprite objects you have in the array should already have their respective positions declared (object.position = CGPointMake(x, y);) and be added to the view.

Other important issues to keep in mind are:

> The shapes of the physics bodies passed into this method are used to create a new physics body whose covered area is the union of the areas of its children. These areas do not need to be contiguous. If there is space between two parts, other bodies may be able to pass between these parts. However, the physics body is treated as a single connected body, meaning that a force or impulse applied to the body affects all of the pieces as if they were held together with an indestructible frame.

Comment: i did like this:   bikee = [SKSpriteNode node];
        bikee.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithBodies:@[leftCircle, rightCircle, bike]];
        bikee.position = CGPointMake(200, 300);
        bikee.size = CGSizeMake(40, 50);
        bikee.physicsBody.mass = 0.1;
        bikee.physicsBody.dynamic = YES;
        bikee.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = YES;
        bikee.physicsBody.restitution = 0;
        bikee.physicsBody.friction = 0;
        bikee.physicsBody.allowsRotation = YES;
        bikee.name = @"bikee";
        //[self addChild:bikee];

Comment: What does the crash message say?

Comment: in the end of the report it says: libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: Post the first few lines please.

Comment: 2014-04-17 19:41:01.050 BikeRider[44237:60b] Cannot find executable for CFBundle 0x984d730 </Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.1.sdk/System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/CertUIFramework.axbundle> (not loaded)
2014-04-17 19:41:01.147 BikeRider[44237:60b] -[SKSpriteNode _shapes]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x99c9b70
2014-04-17 19:41:01.181 BikeRider[44237:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-

Comment: It's complaining about an object called BikeRider. Does this object have a physics body and defined location?

Comment: Didn't understand your last response. Make sure all the objects you are including have a physics body and a location set. As a precaution, I would not mix individual objects and arrays. Do either or. At least when you are troubleshooting.